# What is the rule of multiple borrowing in binary subtraction?

Tags: math, binary, subtraction

11000 
-   111 
= 10001

Below is the procedure, it seems that when doing a multiple borrowing, the value of a borrowed position will never change?

So, for instance, in this example, when doing this subtraction, the last '0' will need to borrow from a 1, finally it find a '1' as the second '1', and this second '1' just like a big fan of propagation-animal and feed all the 0 behind with 10?

Is this the rule?

A '1' can fill all the following '0' with '10'?

[image]

Comment: That hand though..

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question.
Borrowing is propagating 1 backwards.
Say :   
   1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 -  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 = 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 

Because we backwards propagate the one from the begging. Of course that's for unsigned calculations since we don't have sign bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the '1' does not fill all the following 0's with '10'

1100 becomes 1 0 '10' 0 0

that can then become 1 0 1 10 0 [as 10 - 1 = 1 in binary]

this then becomes 1 0 1 1 10

now 1 0 1 1 10

. - 0 0 1 1 1

will be 1 0 0 0 1

it acts similar to regular subtraction

Comment: "1 0 '10' 0 0, that can then become 1 0 1 10 0 [as 10 - 1 = 1 in binary]" Thanks for the answer, lost in this procedure, 'as 10-1=1', this is borrowing, I don't see any subtraction here. The subtraction won't start until we borrowed enough 1, right?

Comment: yes you need to pull it all the way through before you can start doing any subtraction operations on it and the subtraction was splitting the 
10 into a 1 10 by pulling out a 1 [effectively subtracting a 1 which is borrowing]

Comment: OK :) Surely I will, last question, where is the '1' in this '10-1'?

Comment: so in its basically '10'-'01' which gives you '01' which is the same as '1'